# "gegenüber etw. [Dat.] geduldig sein" or "mit etw. [Dat.] geduldig sein"

Tags: preposition, adjective, noun

Which preposition can one use with *Geduld* or *geduldig sein*? Are they both the same?

Example with *geduldig*:

> Sei geduldig gegenüber den Plagen

or

> Sei geduldig mit den Plagen

Example with *Geduld*:

> Die Geduld gegenüber den weltlichen Plagen

or

> Die Geduld mit den weltlichen Plagen

Comment: Your use case seems to be some religious text (as you explicitly mentioned *weltlich*). That might have quite some impact on answers, because there are theological terms and phrases that would not (or no longer) be used in contemporary German in any other context. So it might help if you told us what you need this for (translating a specific existing text or creating a new (pseudo-) religious text for some novel or game).

Comment: Usually, being patient is something you are with a person. I personally wouldn't use it with *Plagen*. *Geduld* implies some kind of expectation that has yet to be satisfied, but you don't expect anything from a *Plage* except perhaps for it to end. What you could say is something like *Ertrage die weltlichen Plagen mit Geduld/geduldig* (because you know that your suffering is finite, you can bear it patiently). Phrases like that can be found in many christian texts.

Comment: @Hulk: Man kann auch geduldig mit Tieren oder Geräten sein und ebenso mit Ereignissen, die sich im Zeitlauf ändern (Plagen, Krankheiten, Wetterzustände), auch wenn der Anlass geduldig zu sein eher in relegiösen Köpfen auftaucht, die eine Instrumentalisierung der Krankheit/Plage durch eine Gottheit vermuten, die jemanden auf die Probe stellen will.

Comment: @userunknown Ja - das ist einer der Gründe, warum mich der Kontext interssiert hätte. Es ist mir unklar, welches Konzept ausgedrückt werden soll. Im Falle einer Instrumentalisierung der Plage als agierende Entität hast du recht, beide Formulierungen sind dann möglich und unterscheiden sich bestenfalls in sehr subtilen Nuancen.

Answer (score 2):

You use *die Geduld* for sentences like:

> Ich habe viel Geduld. (I have a lot of patience.)

*Geduldig sein*, on the other hand, means *being patient*.

Germans also say *habe (etwas) Geduld* (*have some patience*) more often instead of *sei geduldig*.

Answer (score 1):

Beide.

Mehr ist nicht zu sagen; beide sind korrekt.

Comment: Dies beanwortet aber die Frage nicht, ob sie dieselbe Bedeutung haben. Also, mehr ist doch zu sagen.

Answer (score 1):

The preposition does not matter in my experience. Having grown up in Southern Germany, *geduldig mit* is a little more common than the *geduldig gegenüber*, but both are correct. Dito for *Geduld mit/gegenüber*.

The benefactor of patience is more interesting here, I think. While there might be special texts using it that way, I don't think you can have *Geduld* with something that is not a person, institution, group etc. One of the commenters pointed out you can have *Geduld mit/gegenüber* diseases, the weather, natural events etc, but I disagree in the sense that I have not heard or read someone using it that way and find it odd.
This might have changed in time.
Particularly the given example "Die Geduld gegenüber den weltlichen Plagen" sounds quite strange to me. My reference point is 2015 Standard German as spoken in Munich though, so in special domains or in past versions of the language, it might have been valid to connect *Geduld mit* with a thing, concept etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite tricky to answer because there is more than one aspect you have to take into account.

1. *Gegenüber* is placed in front of a noun only as an exception to the rule. It is usually placed after the noun. Here are some examples from [duden.de](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/gegenueber_Praeposition):

   - gegenüber dem Rathaus / (auch:) dem Rathaus gegenüber steht die
     Kirche
   - Ludwigshafen liegt Mannheim gegenüber
   - sie ist älteren Leuten gegenüber besonders höflich
   - mir gegenüber wagt er das nicht zu sagen
   - er ist gegenüber allen Reformen/allen Reformen gegenüber sehr zurückhaltend
   - sie ist dir gegenüber im Vorteil
   - gegenüber dem vergangenen Jahr verdient er mehr

   You can see from these examples that you rather place *gegenüber* before the noun like a "classic" preposition when it refers to a more abstract entity (*Reformen*, *vergangenes Jahr*) as opposed to nouns indicating real persons or things. Whereas this would fit in with *Plagen*, this word is no longer used in everyday German but confined to literary use and a religious context, as Hulk pointed out in the first comment. As a feeling, saying

   > geduldig den Plagen gegenüber

   would seem more appropriate, syntactically. But there remains a semantic issue, as *gegenüber* isn't really the appropriate choice for **introducing a condition you can't interact with**. For this, you have better alternatives, like

   > geduldig angesichts der Plagen
2. *Geduldig sein **mit***, as has also been pointed out in a comment, **indicates an active way of dealing with a person or an object** as opposed to a situation:

   > Ich war bisher sehr geduldig mit dir, aber jetzt reicht es mir!
   >   Ich hatte viel Geduld mit dieser verdammten Waschmaschine, aber jetzt kommt sie auf den Müll!

   but you wouldn't say, "Ich war bisher sehr geduldig mit dem Wetter" because there is no way of actively dealing with the weather. Which also pertains to *Plagen*, as you can't command them, either.
3. Then there is the question in what context you wanted to use this phrase. As it was put in the first version of your question (is since has been edited to *Sei geduldig...*), you can only use it as an apposition:

   > Geduldig angesichts der Plagen, war er ein Vorbild für alle anderen Gläubigen.

   But *geduldig* is primarily used as an adverb:

   > Geduldig wartete sie, bis sie an der Reihe war.
   >   Er ertrug geduldig alle Plagen.
4. Used in an imperative, both *gegenüber* and *mit* are problematic as they practically summon you to "do something", whereas *geduldig* and *Geduld* imply, as Webster's Dictionary puts it for the English equivalent *patience*, **the bearing of provocation, misfortune, pain etc. without complaint** — in other words, doing nothing.

So, the best way to say that somebody should bear troubles etc. patiently is to just say it:

> Ertrage die Plagen mit Geduld.
>   Ertrage geduldig alle Plagen.

If you want to use *Geduld* in the context of *Plagen* as a philosophical or religious category, for example, the best choice would be *angesichts*:

> Die Geduld angesichts der Plagen.
>   Geduld angesichts von Plagen